# XMLReader() in PHP - parsing attributes in multiple elements with the same name

Tags: php, xmlreader

Im using XMLReader to parse XML but i've come across a situation where two elements have the same name and not sure how to deal with it

the elements in question are

```
<field name="latitude" value="51.4070767"/>
<field name="longitude" value="-0.6366062"/>
```

I want to pull in the two value fields into seperate strings.

I can pull in the first one using this method

```
$bp = $product->fields->field["value"]; ###gives 51.4070767
```

but how do i access the second? (-0.6366062)

Cheers

Comment: Is the tag containing the <field> tags is <fields>? I don't know much about the XML reader. Maybe there is a way to split all of theses field into an array.

Comment: yes the orig tag is '<fields>
<field name="latitude" value="51.4070767"/>
<field name="longitude" value="-0.6366062"/>
</fields>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `field` an array, so that you can do:

```
$product->fields->field[0]["value"];
$product->fields->field[1]["value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just one idea...
You can find the node by attribute (getAttribute) and after you can select the node using moveToElement.

But the best option is use the simpleXML, where you can use XPath to find what you want.